# Linux Debian Run commands at boot in init script

Tags: linux, debian, init

I'm new to Linux (obviously) and I need to run some commands whenever my Linux server boots without typing them into the console manually.

I have this file called overpass.conf that runs on boot perfectly:

```
description 'Overpass API dispatcher daemon'

env DB_DIR=/var/www/osm/db/
env EXEC_DIR=/var/www/osm/

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

pre-start script
    rm $DB_DIR/osm3s* || true
    rm /dev/shm/osm3s* || true
end script

exec $EXEC_DIR/bin/dispatcher --osm-base --db-dir=$DB_DIR
```

However, I want to also run the following:

```
cp -pR "/root/osm-3s_v0.7.4/rules" "/var/www/osm/db/"

nohup /var/www/osm/bin/dispatcher --areas --db-dir="/var/www/osm/db/" & 

chmod 666 "/var/www/osm/db/osm3s_v0.7.4_areas"

nohup /var/www/osm/bin/rules_loop.sh "/var/www/osm/db/" &
```

I have tried adding them to the bottom of the file, adding exec to the execution commands and even tried removing the quotes, then testing with `start overpass` but it throws errors if I add any commands to the original ones.

How can I go about executing those 4 commands after the original ones? I'm a noob in distress. Thanks!

**Edit**

I solved it with these commands:

```
vi /etc/init.d/mystartup.sh
```

-Add commands to the script

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/mystartup.sh    
update-rc.d mystartup.sh defaults 99
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3):

There's also

```
/etc/rc.local
```

that is executed at the end of the boot process.